# Ad Hoc iPhone build crashes twice after first installation, but then there is no problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, crash, adhoc

I've just distributed my iPhone app to a couple of beta-testers using Ad Hoc distribution and TestFlight. After the install the app crashes twice after opening then afterwards works absolutely fine.

**Is there some sort of general reason behind this?** Would this cause a rejection from App Store submission? Do you think this is an important glitch that should definitely be adressed or is it no biggie?

Comment: You need to add the crash report to your question.  The crash report can point you in the direction of why this crash is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your app is doing, but maybe some initialization steps which depend on each other are through after the second crash so the app runs fine.

And yes Apple won't like this. Apps crashing on startup are not good, even if they run on third launch.